# Strlen is not giving correct output

Tags: php, string, strlen

I have a string which I retrieve from a database, I want to calculate the length of the string without spaces but it is displaying a larger value of length(21 characters greater than the actual count) I have removed tab and newline characters and also the php and html tags but no result! I have tried almost every function on the w3schools php reference but I'm unable to find any success. I also have observed that if I don't retrieve the value from the database and input it like this:

`$string = "my string";`

I get the correct length, please help me. Here is the code:

```
if($res_tutor[0]['tutor_experience']){
        $str = trim(strip_tags($res_tutor[0]['tutor_experience']));
            $str = $this->real_string($str);
            $space = substr_count($str, ' ');
            $experience  = strlen($str) -  $space;


function real_string($str)
{
    $search  = array("\t","\n","\r\n","\0","\v");
    $replace = array('','','','','');
    $str = str_replace($search,$replace,$str);
    return $str;
}
```

And this is the string from the database but as you can see above I have removed all php and html tags using `strip_tags()` :

```
<span class=\"experience_font\">You are encouraged to write a short description of yourself, teaching experience and teaching method. You may use the guidelines below to assist you in your writing.<br />
   <br />
   .Years of teaching experience<br />
   .Total number of students taught<br />
   .Levels &amp; subjects that you have taught<br />
   .The improvements that your students have made<br />
   .Other achievements/experience (Relief teaching, a tutor in a tuition centre, Dean&#39;s list, scholarship, public speaking etc.)<br />
   .For Music (Gigs at Esplanade, Your performances in various locations etc.)</span><br />
   &nbsp;</p>
```

and when I print it, it displays as:

```
<span class=\"experience_font\">You are encouraged to write a short description of yourself, teaching experience and teaching method. You may use the guidelines below to assist you in your writing.<br />
   <br />
   .Years of teaching experience<br />
   .Total number of students taught<br />
   .Levels &amp; subjects that you have taught<br />
   .The improvements that your students have made<br />
   .Other achievements/experience (Relief teaching, a tutor in a tuition centre, Dean&#39;s list, scholarship, public speaking etc.)<br />
   .For Music (Gigs at Esplanade, Your performances in various locations etc.)</span><br />
   &nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: If you're viewing this in a browser, make sure there aren't any html tags and whatnot in there. Just because you can't SEE the extra characters means very little.

Comment: there were extra tags and i have removed the using strip_tags()

Comment: i don't get it ... i ran your code with input you entered and it works ok for me. it must be related to what you got from db... you need to add more code, try to copy text from db directly or something similar.

Comment: yes it is related to the database, the string coming from the database is behaving so, and when i print it the output is as the string i have given in question above. the text in the database is as pasted above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Svetilo, not to be rude just wanted to post my findings, your str_replace worked wonderfully, except for the fact that I was still outputting incorrect values with it in the order that you currently have, I found that the following worked flawlessly.

```
$string = str_replace(array("\t","\r\n","\n","\0","\v"," "),'', $string);
mb_strlen($string, "UTF-8");
```

Changing around the \r\n & \n made the str_replace not strip out the \n from the \r\n leaving it just a \r.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Try using mb_strlen. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php
Its more more precise.

```
mb_strlen($str,"UTF-8")
```

Where UTF-8 is your default encoding...
To remove all freespaces try something like that..

```
 $string = str_replace(array("\t","\n","\r\n","\0","\v"," "),"",$string);
 mb_strlen($string, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: sorry not working, same result!
and my encoding is "ASCII"
thanx, yes bro, i have tried that above.

Comment: worked like a charm to me... tks