# Strlen doesn't count the characters correctly

Tags: php

That's my code

```
$devmsg = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['devmsg']);
if(strlen($devmsg) <= 200) {
do something
} else {
do some other thing
}
```

When I add to the message some special chars such as "(" "[" "." "{" and so on the strlen() counts wrong.. If my message is ~160-180 characters long and there are specials chars in it , the if operator just returns false and goes to else.. I thought the problem's here `$db->real_escape_string` and then removed it but still got the same result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159953/strlen-is-not-giving-correct-output

Comment: Does your string contain multibyte characters? edit: To slow. But in case you might want to read: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11034058/2912456

Comment: The link was very useful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So you're saying that `strlen('([.{')` is not equal to 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be a UTF-8 problem.

Try to pass the text through utf8_decode() first:

```
<?php 
$length = strlen(utf8_decode($s)); 
?>
```

`utf8_decode()` converts characters that are not in ISO-8859-1 to '?', which, for the purpose of counting, is quite alright.

Comment: This works perfectly and it seems that's the easiest way. I'll chose your answer in 7 minutes.